# Assign the body elements as environment variable in Postman

Tags: postman

I have a scenario where i need to pass the body element values to environmen variable and access it in another API.

Below is the body,

```
{
"firstName" : "James",
"lastName" : "Joseph",
"email" : "{{timestamp}}@test.com",
"password" : "{{timestamp}}",
"country" : 16
}
```

Below is the Pre-req script,

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("timestamp", (new 
Date).getTime());
// I have copied the Body and paste it in a variable called Obj in Pre- 
req
// Then i used the below script to get the body
pm.environment.set("rawBody", JSON.stringify(obj));
```

But the environmental values of timestamp , email and password is coming as below. The timestamp value is correct and other two are wrong.

```
timestamp = 1566076106769
email = {{timestamp}}@test.com
password = {{timestamp}}
```

The timestamp value is not getting substituted in email and password,i want the environmental variable value to set as,

```
email = 1566076106769@test.com
password = 1566076106769
```

So how can i assign the body element value to an environment/global variable to use in another API call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the values of body to variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541838/get-the-values-of-body-to-variables)