# Get the values of body to variables

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a scenario where i need to pass the body values to an environment variable and use those in another API. In Postman

Below is the body,

```
{
  "firstName" : "Firstname",
  "lastName" : "lastname",
  "email" : "{{timestamp}}@test.com",
  "password" : "{{timestamp}}",
  "country" : 8l16
 }
```

Below is the Pre-req script,

```
  postman.setEnvironmentVariable("timestamp", (new 
  Date).getTime());
  // I have copied the Bodyand paste it in a variable called Obj in 
   Pre-req
 // Then i used the below script to get the body
  pm.environment.set("rawBody", JSON.stringify(obj));
```

But the environmental values of timestamp , email and password is coming as below. The timestamp value is correct and other two are wrong.

```
 timestamp = 1566076106769
 email = {{timestamp}}@test.com
  password = {{timestamp}}
```

The timestamp value is not getting substituted in email and password,i want the environmental variable value to set as,

Expected values,

```
 email = 1566076106769@test.com
 password = 1566076106769
```

So how can i assign the body element value to an environment/global variable to use in another API call?

Comment: What version of PostMan are you using? Your code is working for me as expected, except of the line  pm.environment.set("rawBody", JSON.stringify(obj));

Answer (score 0):

Easy. You have set the environmental variable but never got it.
 "{ }" doesn't work in code of *Tests* and *Pre-request Script*.
Make it like this:

```
const timestamp = pm.environment.get('timestamp');
email = `${timestamp} @test.com`; 
password = timestamp;
```